# qlpreviewcontroller in ios6

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios6, qlpreviewcontroller

By using qlpreviewcontroller getting the output in ios 4.3. i am showing the documents from the remote url.

In ios 6 it shows the empty view of the qlpreviewcontroller. Need to fix this issue .  Any tutorials for the qlpreviewcontroller in ios 6.

need to develop the application in the xcode 3.6 to overcome this issue is this possible to fix this issue.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

QLPreviewController will only load files from a file URL. You have to load them from disk, so if you want to use QLPreviewController, you have to download the file and cache it on disk first.

I'm not completely sure what you mean when referring to Xcode 3.6, but you won't be able to create iOS6 apps using it.